# Can one configure Prettier to a more human-readable boolean expression formatting?

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

If I have a long boolean expression, even if it has nesting it's getting formatted with every variable on a new line followed by the operator. Which arguably makes it less readable to the human eye.

What prettier gives me:

```
  private static Boolean returnBool() {
    return booleanExpressionVariable1 &&
      booleanExpressionVariable2 &&
      (booleanExpressionVariable3 ||
      booleanExpressionVariable4 ||
      booleanExpressionVariable5);
  }
```

What I expect this to look like:

```
  private static Boolean returnBool() {
    return booleanExpressionVariable1 &&
      booleanExpressionVariable2 &&
      (
        booleanExpressionVariable3 ||
        booleanExpressionVariable4 ||
        booleanExpressionVariable5
      )
    ;
  }
```